# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Tags: php, parsing, variables

A person gets the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE
```

from the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT story,video FROM `storycodes` WHERE `code` = '$code"';
```

Comment: You answered your own question rather quickly

Comment: A person posts on stackoverflow and checks the code to realize that solving this parse error is trivial, even for a non-programmer and all it takes is a bit of reading that doesn't exceed 20 seconds of person's time.

Comment: I posted this to share my knowledge with others, not to ask for help on something I already know the answer for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error code results from placing the quotes in the wrong order. In this code it says '$code"' when it should be '$code'"

The fixed code would look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT story,video FROM `storycodes` WHERE `code` = '$code'";
                                                                    ^^--here
```

Comment: it's generally a good idea to put a visual indicator of where you made the change, especially when you're swapping two characters that at a glance are very similar. +1 for the right answer, though.

Comment: @MarcB He did the question and answered it straight away.. it's kind of weird.

Comment: @serpro... *blink blink* I think I need to get some coffee or something. didn't even notice that.

Comment: @SERPRO - No, it's not. That's actually [one of the new capabilities of the question-asking interface](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).

Comment: @BradLarson well I knew that you can answer your own question. It's just that I thought you can't answer it instantly. :)

Comment: Why did I get minused for no research effort when I asked it for Q&A so I could share my knowledge. That is very unfair. People need to look closer.

Comment: @michaelb Life AinnaFair, Kiddo, But Never Give Up... :)  The benefits far outweigh the occasional bullshit and every now and then you might find you sorta grudgingly agree, later, with what goes down.  Know I have, so I put up with random stuff I disagree with.  Cheers!  and ...screenshots or it didn't happen